# Запуск jar файла из консоли

Tags: java, cmd, консоль

Программа должна скачивать файлы по HTTP протоколу.
Входные параметры:
l – ссылка на файл.
p – путь на файловой системе, куда нужно сохранить файл.
n – имя файла.
Её запуск через консоль должен выглядеть примерно так:
java -jar myTheBestJar.jar -l http://example.com/cat.jpg -p D:\files\cats -n black_cat.jpg

Это часть задания. Не могу понять, что в данном случае значат -l, -p, -n. Это аргументы, которые пользователь пишет, программа их считывает и понимает, что дальше будет значение для этого аргумента?

Или это встроенные команды в консоли, которые что-то делают? Долго уже ищу, но везде сталкиваюсь с тем, что просто примеры просто с аргментами в строку(типа java -jar Java.jar arg1 arg2 ...).

Comment: Очевидно что программе myTheBestJar.jar после запуска будет передана строка с параметрами "-l http://example.com/cat.jpg -p D:\files\cats -n black_cat.jpg" где после -l написана ссылка на файл, после -p путь куда сохранить файл, -n имя файла. Буквы l n p это значения параметров которые нужны чтобы понять где какой.

Comment: спасибо, что развеяли, я наконец-то понял! Т.е. это как флаги, по которым искать? Т.е. в принципе они могут меняться местами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить параметры можно таким образом

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String l="", p="", n="";
        for (int i=0;i<args.length;++i) {
            String arg = args[i];
            if (arg.equals("-l")) {
                l = args[++i];
            } else if (arg.equals("-p")) {
                p = args[++i];
            } else if (arg.equals("-n")) {
                n = args[++i];
            }
        }
        System.err.println("l = " + l);
        System.err.println("p = " + p);
        System.err.println("n = " + n);
    }
}
```